# how to open files as read only in openoffice

Tags: openoffice, documents, read-only

I'm a student and I often find myself opening lecture notes (in PPT format) to study. I don't need to edit them (and I don't want to accidentally edit them). After opening the file I usually click on the `Edit File` button to enter read only mode.

Is there a way that I can open the document directly as read only?

Thanks

EDIT: I'm using Ubuntu, but the files are stored in an NTFS partition, which is mounted as read-write. It would be nice if I can pass a parameter to OpenOffice, and not have to change the files themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenOffice.org comes with a program called `viewdoc` that will open any OpenDocument file as read-only. In my installation (3.2.1), however this program is missing.

No matter, though:

```
/opt/openoffice.org3/program/soffice -view FILE
```

will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you set them as "read-only" in through your OS properties, Open Office will also open them in read-only mode.

For Windows, you can right click on your file(s) and choose Properties. Then, enable the "Read-only" checkbox in the Attributes section.

Answer (score 0):

You could save them as PDFs.

Comment: nice idea, but that's an overkill